# What problems can I have if my docker image is 2.5GB & how can I reduce the size?

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning

I have a Python based machine learning project that I want to dockerize. I have several heavy dependencies, like, [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib), [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition), [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) etc.

Following is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt update \
    && apt -y upgrade \
    && apt install -y python3 \
    && apt install -y python3-pip \
    && apt install -y poppler-utils \
    && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt install -y postgresql

COPY dlib-19.17.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl /app/dlib-19.17.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install dlib-19.17.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD gunicorn -t 300 --workers 5 --bind  0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi
```

After building the image, it turns out to be 2.5 GB. Is it ok to have an image this big? If no, how can I reduce the size while maintaining the dependencies.

Comment: The size is fine. However, what can be a big problem is if you need to build your images every time you test your code. I once worked on a project where it took 30 minutes to test any change. Absolutely unworkable. You want to either have a development environment where you don't have to build images, or use a volume mount or something to be able to push code changes without rebuilding.

Comment: You might be able to use  [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to decrease the image size.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the response. I think I should be looking at the volume mounts since it's only the code that will keep changing, do you have any resources that I can look into?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks. I will check.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the size is a problem actually depends on whether you just want to have a container, or you want to distribute and scale it. In the latter case, size is a problem because it slows the process.

What you need to do to reduce the size is to use multi-stage. Here you have a sample of my own https://github.com/eez0/docker-samples/blob/master/Dockerfile_python.

The bottom line is to differentiate between the building and the running process. For example, currently you install all the dependencies, but some **might be** only used at building time, so it's safe to remove them.

If for some reason you don't want to get into multi-stage, then use `--no-install-recommends` to install only what's necessary, and remove all the unnecessary build dependencies and `apt` cache at the end. Also, try to use a smaller base image, for example `python:3.7-slim`

Comment: I would also add that a database is best used in a separate container probably with a volume mounted from the host or network for persistence